# Ansible - Get index of a value and substitute it in jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an inventory file like:

```
[cluster]
node1
node2
node3
node4
```

And I want to create a file on each machine with the file contents as the index of its node.

So;

```
node1, should have a file `myfile.txt` with `0` inside 
node2, should have a file `myfile.txt` with `1` inside 
node3, should have a file `myfile.txt` with `2` inside 
node4, should have a file `myfile.txt` with `3` inside
```

Currently I can access the list in the jinja template with: `groups['cluster']`

How can I use jinja templating to achieve this?

Comment: What is supposed to happen on the last node in the list ?

Comment: edit for clarity

Comment: The list has 4 elements, basically it is just about putting the index into a file on the corresponding node.  The last node will be the same, it should have a file containing its index, 3

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility. Adapt to your own requirements. The key point here if the use of `loop_control` (see the [ansible loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html))

```
- name: Create the needed files locally
  hosts: localhost
  gather_fact: false

  tasks:
    - name: Create a local file for each cluster host with its index as content
      copy:
        dest: "/tmp/myfile_{{ server }}.txt"
        content: "{{ server_index }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['cluster'] }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: server
        index_var: server_index

- name: Copy each files to the desired host
  hosts: cluster
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Copy file from local tmp to host
      copy:
        src: "/tmp/myfile_{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
        dest: /what/ever/path/myfile.txt"
```